# Constraint JAX-WS CXF web service request method invocation to one request per client IP

Tags: java, servlets, locking, jax-ws, cxf

I have a CXF-based web service with a one-way method say:
Service.report()

While a report() from a client is being processed, I want to make another incoming report() from the same client IP wait till the first request is processed. Seen from a client, report() is an atomic operation and successive calls to report() should be processed sequentially.

How can I best implement this locking mechanism? Will I need to implement a per-client queue or is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Will this work with **synchronized report()** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a full blown queue for this. A simple object synchronisation should work

```
static ConcurrentMap syncMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

public void report()
{
   String clientIp =  ...
   syncMap.putIfAbsent(clientIp, new Object()); // just new Object is good enough to sync on
   synchronized(syncMap.get(clientIp))
   {
      //do synchronized stuff.
   }
}
```

Comment: While it's a perfect solution, I would suggest something a bit more robust. With this kind of synchronization you are holding a thread in limbo until it gets a chance to work. If you would use some kind of executor pattern, there would be no need for this __big__ and costly sync IMHO.

Comment: Unless you are using servlet 3.0, you need to keep the worker thread for the HTTP request blocked anyway.

Comment: Thanks @greyfairer! How can I best clear out the client IP from map once I'm done processing the request? Can this cause problems:

`synchronized(syncMap.get(clientIp))
{
  //do synchronized stuff.
  syncMap.remove(clientIp);
}`

Comment: A remove is always atomically, so you can do that securely. But I don't see the necessity. If you exit the synchronized block, the  sync object is unlocked and can be reused in the next call, so you keep it in the map. Unless you're really limited in memory.